# ViewPagerAdapter Cannot display properly in Fragment

Tags: java, android

First I must say sorry, my English is not very good

I have to be in the extends Fragment

Add tablayout and ViewPage on top

Add three Fragments to ViewPageAdapter to switch ViewPage

But I am currently unable to know why my Adapter is showing empty on the emulator

I have found some article but I don't know which one is right for my current situation.

Trouble everyone to give me a response and advice

I will accept it with humility, thanks!

this is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".HomeFragment">


<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:id="@+id/tablayout_fragment_home"
    >

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewpager_fragment_home"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

this is my .java

```
package com.example.teng.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class HomeFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

View view ;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;


public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    return view ;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tablayout_fragment_home);
    viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_fragment_home);
    adapter.AddFragment(new LatestNews(),"Page1");
    adapter.AddFragment(new PopularProduct(),"Page2");
    adapter.AddFragment(new ThemeActivity(),"Page3");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

}

Comment: Share your `ViewPagerAdapter` class with question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set up `TabLayout` in the wrong method.
correct method should be `onActivityCreated`

`onActivityCreated` called initially when activity which is associated with the fragment is created.

The issue was you initialized adapter in OnActvityResult which called when an intent is triggered with `startActivityForResult()`.

Replace below code with your current code.

```
package com.example.teng.myapplication; 

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout; 
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class HomeFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

View view ;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;


public HomeFragment() { 
    // Required empty public constructor 
} 


@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment 
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    return view ;
} 

@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        initComponent();
    }


        // Initialise components and variables
    private void initComponent() {

    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tablayout_fragment_home);
    viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_fragment_home);
    adapter.AddFragment(new LatestNews(),"Page1");
    adapter.AddFragment(new PopularProduct(),"Page2");
    adapter.AddFragment(new ThemeActivity(),"Page3");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }


}
```

**Replace your XML file with below code**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".HomeFragment">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:id="@+id/tablayout_fragment_home"/>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewpager_fragment_home"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Your click is not working just because of **FrameLayout** as **FrameLayout** place control to **top** each other. So changed it to **LinearLayout**.

Comment: Hi ,  @Jaymin master , thanks for your share ,

This effectively solves my current problems , 

When solving problems is very exciting !

But my tabLayout click is not reaction ,

I can't tell which side is wrong.

Comment: @ChaTeng, I have updated my answer with the click solution. please check and replace your XML.

Comment: Hi , @Jaymin I want to achieve this style ,
I need to use Fragment in Fragment (Do not use to switch to new Activity) ,
I can't change to LinearLayout ,
Unless there are other solutions ,
style like this picture :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TZqM3wy1DAjseLUcvtCGJEgBht-Xyy4c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ChaTeng, You can achieve the same thing with the linear layout also.

Comment: Hi , Jaymin , This makes me very excited ,
Although I don't know why it can be used `LinearLayout`,
But this solves the problem that has been bothering me for a long time.
Thank you for solving my problem!

Comment: @Jaymin Is it possible to make something like this, if the page in fragment it is full with GridLayout list create another fragment ?

Comment: @Spritzig, Yes it is but it will make more complex flow to handle the fragments.

Comment: What do you suggest me to do in this case because the user choose how many items will have GridLayout ?

Comment: @Spritzig, You can create an activity to show the GridLayout.

Comment: Could you give me a example because I have a Fragment in that Fragment it is GridLayout how to create an Activity to show GridLayout ?

Comment: @Spritzig, Please show me your app design like a screenshot. So, I can suggest you the approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185781/discussion-between-jaymin-and-spritzig).